# How to create cred configuration file in GCP (python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a cloud function on gcp in Python.

I'm trying to convert this command (in bash) to Python:

```
echo -e "\033[0;34mGenrating client configuration json file  \033[0m"
gcloud  iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config \
projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/$IDENTITY_POOL/providers/$IDENTITY_POOL_PROVIDER \
--service-account=$SA \
--output-file=$ClientConfig \
--aws
```

I tried with no success to figure out what is the equal command from here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.workloadIdentityPools/patch

these are my imports

```
from google.cloud import (
    workflows_v1beta,
    eventarc_v1,
    compute_v1,
    pubsub_v1,
    **iam_v1**
)
```

When `im` trying to define `iam_v1` in the `im` not able to deploy the function at all. The error message is:

> Could not create or update Cloud Run service aqua-onboarding,
> Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'aqua-onboarding-00183-cug' is
> not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed
> to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080
> environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more
> information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a direct SDK call to get this file generated, though please give it a try to use 'google.auth.external_account' package.

We can pass set of parameters and get this credential object generated

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.external_account.html